# Pipeline not picking up all rows/records from source

Tags: streamsets

Stream sets pipeline is not picking up all the records/rows from the source. Am I missing the obvious?

In example,

Source Informix
39,136 rows

StreamSets
Input = 38,926 rows
Output = 38,928 rows

Comment: Hard to say without seeing your pipeline and the query.

Comment: Can you update your question and provide more details about your pipeline including any processors you may have?